# Como limpiar un autocomplete de primefaces convirtiendolo a nulo dando click a un command button en jsf con primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

tengo un problema a la hora de querer dar click en un commandbutton lo que quiero hacer mas que nada es limpiar un autocomplete de primefaces cuando de click, tengo entendido que se tiene volver nulo, este es mi codigo del autocomplete:

```
                <p:autoComplete id="modelodispositivo" 
                                placeholder="Buscar Dispositivo"
                                value="${controlVersionesBean.controlVersion}" 
                                emptyMessage="No hay información con este criterio de búsqueda" 
                                completeMethod="${controlVersionesBean.buscarDispositivo}" 
                                var="modelodispositivo"
                                itemLabel="${modelodispositivo.device_name}"
                                itemValue="${modelodispositivo}"
                                scrollHeight="250"
                                required="true" 
                                converter="entityConverter"
                                forceSelection="true" 
                                requiredMessage="¡Campo requerido!"
                                onkeypress="return alfanumerico(event)"
                                style="width: 20%;"
                                >
                </p:autoComplete>
```

Y este es mi codigo java quiero usar para borrar:

```
  public void Reset() {
        controlVersion = new ControlVersionesDTO();
        controlVersion = null;
        listControlVersionesFiltradas = new ArrayList<>();
        listaDispositivos = new ArrayList<>();
        listaDispositivosFilter = new ArrayList<>();
//        listControlVersionesFiltradas=null;
//        listaDispositivos=null;
//        listControlVersiones=null;
        //controlVersion.setDevice_name(null);

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("data_table");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("modelodispositivo");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("cancelar()");

    }
```

controlVersion es el nombre de mi objeto, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, saludos y quedo al pendiente.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo pude solucionar, dejo el codigo:

```
listControlVersiones.clear();
```

Solo busqué la lista que llena el autocomplete y solo usé el clear para borrar la lista y ya con eso desaparecio, espero y les sirvan, saludos.